# How to detect if a RGB is fully transparent?

Tags: java, colors, alpha

In java, I want to make a fully transparent RGBA, and I do that by using

```
public static int getTransparentRGB() {
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int new_pixel = (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
    return new_pixel;
}

    Color color = new Color(getTransparentRGB());
    System.out.println(color.getAlpha()); // -> 255  ?!
```

I purposely keep all rgba values 0. However after I create the `Color` object with the rgba value as the constructor, if I call `.getAlpha()`, I get `255` even though I made the rgb value with a `0` alpha. If it returns `255`, how could I tell the difference between a `Color` object that wasn't transparent, because that would also have a `255` alpha.

I expect the color object to return a `0` alpha based on the function above.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: This is not solution to your problem, but if you don't end up figuring this out, you can always do this: `new Color(r,g,b,a).getRGB()`

Comment: This actually worked well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the constructor [`Color(int, boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-boolean-) to supply the alpha value for your color. The [constructor you are using](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-) changes the alpha value to 255.